# CSS issue on mobile devices with country code dropdown (intl-tel-input)

Tags: android, html, css, resize, intl-tel-input

I'm using this library to show country code and flag to users: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

On desktop everything works as expected. Even on screen resize the response is as expected. The problem appears when I test the page on a mobile device, using Android Chrome.

Here is the problem:

[image]

The app doesn't allow users to choose other countries (A space for scrolling is hidden - the user only see default selected country).

I tried using `z-index:9999` but it didn't work.

Here is the CSS implementation:

```
.intl-tel-input .country-list {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

I am not sure why this doesn't seem to work on mobile devices.

Comment: Did you try using a different browser? Can you include your html specifically for that section where the select is? Your styles tells us that .country-list exists within .intl-tel-input which doesn't quite make sense so seeing the html would help see how you named your html elements.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when input was in a modal/dialog.
On mobile, the dropdown will be in the `<body>` at the end of it, because this:
https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/blob/v16.0.8/src/js/intlTelInput.js#L117

There is an option to set the container element, try to change the `dropdownContainer` option.

Comment: i tried this, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

[Image show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW5rY.png)

I had the same mobile problem and dealt with js that might help someone. Everyone can refer.

I have handled the check that handles the click on the flag that repositions the position of the displayed list country.
The code that I see is working.

```
 iti = window.intlTelInput(inputPhoneNumber, intlTelInputOptions)
 iti.isMobile= false;
 $('.iti__selected-flag').click(function () {
   if ($('body.iti-mobile').length) {
       $('.iti--container').css('top', $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + 35 + 'px');
       $('.iti--container').css('left', $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px');
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

iti.isMobile = false;

```
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            positionItiContainer();
        });

        $('.iti__selected-flag').click(function () {
            positionItiContainer();
        });

        var positionItiContainer = function() {
            if ($('body.iti-mobile').length) {
                var phoneElement = document.getElementById('phone');
                var selectedFlag = document.querySelector('.iti__selected-flag');
                var phoneRect = phoneElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                var selectedFlagRect = selectedFlag.getBoundingClientRect();

                $('.iti--container').css('top', selectedFlagRect.bottom + 'px');
                $('.iti--container').css('left', selectedFlagRect.left + 'px');
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please add detail about the issue, and why this fixes the problem, to make your comment more understandable

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug I also found in the library. When I inspect I can see that the max-height of the dropdown has changed. You can overwrite that max-height by adding this

```
.iti-mobile .intl-tel-input .country-list {
    max-height: 200px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
iti__country-list{white-space:nowrap}
```